# The console window automatically closes abnormally in windows10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

When I open Powershell or CMD in Windows 10, the console window automatically closes after half a minute, no matter what I do. When I open a c++ program, no matter what I do, the console window closes after half a minute. But when I opened Task Manager， I found that the c++ program was still running in the background.
I don't know what caused such a mistake and how to fix it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know the cause, I fixed the problem by updating the system.